# MySQL compare two results and show delta

Tags: mysql, sorting, delta

So I have a table called "food" and in this table I have two columns 'groceryBag' and 'item' as follows:

```
groceryBag    item
----------    -----
1             banana
1             eggs
2             ham
1             apple
1             chicken
2             apple
2             eggs
```

My goal is to return the results that are different between bag 1 and bag 2.  So in my example above the results would be:

```
groceryBag    item
----------    -----
1             banana
2             ham
1             chicken
```

originally, I was going to approach this with python by checking to see if each item in bag 1 is also in bag 2, then check to see if each item in bag 2 is in bag 1.  This becomes very time consuming when the bags are very large. I also thought about outputting both query results into two files then diffing them. I was hoping that there was an eligant MySQL way of comparing two query results and only showing the deltas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of rows for each item. If an item is only in 1 row, then it's only in 1 bag.

```
SELECT MAX(bag) AS bag, item
FROM foo
GROUP BY item
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

what I was looking for was:

```
select * from (
select f.groceryBag, f.item as 1item from foo f where f.groceryBag = 1) 
as q1 where q1.1item no in ( 
select f.item from foo f where f.groceryBag = 2)
```

Then do the reverse to get what is in bag 2 but not in bag 1.